# From a given set of straight lines, how to find the points, lying on any line, having minimum y co-ordinate at a particular x?

Tags: java, geometry

A naive solution would be to iterate over each straight line equation (~1e5 of them), substitute the 'x' with the given value, obtain 'y', and compare this 'y' with the 'y's obtained from the other straight line equations. This solution however, fails to complete within the Time Limit if number of queries is large (~1e5). Is there any efficient way to find the minimum 'y' for a particular 'x'?

The JAVA code, which fails:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Competitive_Programming
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int N, M;
    static StLine[] lines;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i, j;

        N = sc.nextInt();   // Number of straight lines (~1e5)
        lines = new StLine[N];
        for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            double m = sc.nextDouble(); // slope
            double c = sc.nextDouble(); //y-intercept
            lines[i] = new StLine(m, c);
        }

        M = sc.nextInt();   // Number of queries (~1e5)
        for(i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            double x = sc.nextDouble(); // The X co-ordinate
            double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                minY = Math.min(minY, lines[j].YatX(x));
            System.out.println(minY);   // Minimum Y co-ordinate
        }
    }
}
class StLine
{
    double slope, yintercept;
    StLine(double m, double c)
    {
        slope = m;  yintercept = c;
    }
    double YatX(double x)
    {
        return x * slope + yintercept;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that takes too long?

Comment: If this is a programming question, include a language. If it is purely a math question, go post this in https://mathoverflow.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locus of the lowest y for any x is a convex polyline with at most N-1 vertices.

You can construct it incrementally by adding one line at a time. The update of the polyline isn't very difficult when done the naive way: for every segment, check if it crosses the new line, and only keep the portions "below". Make sure to keep the left-to-right ordering of the vertices.

I suspect that this operation can be done more efficiently by dichotomic-like processes, but that requires more sophisticated data structures.

When you have obtained the final polyline, it takes a simple dichotomic search to find the y for a given x.

[image]

Comment: I even think that by some form of duality, the construction can be turned to the problem of the convex hull of a point set, which is easily solved in time O(N Log N).